# url parameter rewrite with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help to rewrite an url parameter with htacces.

The url which comes from my affiliate partners looks like:

```
http://example.com/#colo=123abcABC
```

And I need ist like this:

```
http://example.com/#sv=123abcABC
```

I tried this htaccess entry:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^colo=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?sv=%2 [R=301,L]
```

But this is not working. Can anybody help me please?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: The part of that URL after the `#` is called a fracture. It is actually _not_ sent to the server at all, it is a client side thing. That is the reason why you certainly will not be able to somehow capture or rewrite that.

Comment: Thank you very much for information.